# How to use Excel or Google Sheets COUNTUNIQUEIFS where the unique cell meets two conditions in same criteria column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, count-unique

I have a call log that I want to determine the number of answered and unanswered ***unique*** callers. However, if a caller has both statuses answered and answered, I want it to count as answered, since someone talked to that caller at some point. I prefer Google Sheets countuniqueifs, but Excel will work fine too.

[image]

I want the following results:

| status | # of unique callers |
| --- | --- |
| answered | 3 |
| unanswered | 1 (excludes those with both answered and unanswered) |

For a unique caller with both unanswered and answered status, we want to consider them as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those that are answered:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,COUNTIFS(C2:C,"answered",B2:B,B2:B)))
```

Those that are unanswered:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,COUNTIFS(C2:C,"answered",B2:B,B2:B)=0))
```

Or rather, just minus the two from eachother:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)-<OutcomeOfFirstFormula>)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I used the total_unique minus answered.

Answer (score -1):

use for answered:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(SORTN(SORT(B2:C, 2, 1), 9^9, 2, 1, 0), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 'answered'")))
```

and for unanswered:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(SORTN(SORT(B2:C, 2, 1), 9^9, 2, 1, 0), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 'unanswered'")))
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't quite work for me because not all the phone numbers are in numeric, so maybe the sorting didn't work.